# JavaScript/HTML - SVG Arrowhead not showing up on line element

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dom, d3.js

I want to create a line with an arrowhead. The line element is contained in a group container in an SVG. I'm using the following code to add the arrow head definition to the SVG.

```
var defs = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "defs");
var marker = document.createElementNS(
  "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  "marker"
);
marker.setAttributeNS(null, "id", "triangle");
marker.setAttributeNS(null, "refX", 10);
marker.setAttributeNS(null, "refY", 5);
marker.setAttributeNS(null, "markerUnits", 110);
marker.setAttributeNS(null, "markerWidth", 100);
marker.setAttributeNS(null, "markerHeight", 100);
marker.setAttributeNS(null, "orient", "auto");
var path = document.createElementNS("http;//www.w3.org/2000/svg", "path");
path.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "black");
path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", "M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z");
marker.appendChild(path);
defs.appendChild(marker);
currentSVG.appendChild(defs);
```

However, the arrow head is not showing up. It shows up only when I open the developer tools and edit the marker defition as SVG and change it slightly to make a change. Without editing in the developer tools, the SVG definiton and the marker-end although present does not show an arrow head.

Comment: you have a typo: http; instead of http: when you create the path for the marker. Also markerUnits can take only a keyword either userSpaceOnUse or strokeWidth. 110 is not a valid value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake where you typed a semicolon instead of a colon.

```
var path = document.createElementNS(“http; << here
```